# Drupal uses 100% CPU

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am a drupal developer , I used to create thumbnails for the uploaded images via Image cache actions in drupal 7.0 it takes about 100% CPU utilization. I use amazon EC2 with m1.small as my server and stored images in amazon s3 bucket, but i am creating the thumbnails in my EC2 server and then pushing to S3 via cron job, i also tried creating thumbnails using normal PHP (using imagecreatefromjpeg() and imagejpeg() functions) and setting it as a cron job for every 5min ..
, which also takes around 100% of cpu.

I tried to increase the "apc.shm_size" in php.ini
but no improvements.

How can i reduce the CPU usage?Any suggestions please..

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You are creating thumbnails from probably large image files. That *obviously* needs CPU power, so it will go to 100%. There's nothing you can do against it.